# typeorm: force mysql2 if mysql is installed

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, mysql-connector

I know this is a special use case, but I have both `mysql` and `mysql2` packages installed and I need to test both of them.
However as my understanding typeorm will first check if `mysql` is in the `node_modules` and use it.

How can I force `mysql2` to be used instead? Or programmatically switch between them?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem recently, After a period of research (including reading the source code) I found a way.

#### 1 Programmatically:

```js
// for 0.2.x
{
  driver: PlatformTools.load('mysql2'),
  //...other options
}
// for 0.3.x
{
  connectorPackage: 'mysql2'
  //other options
}
```

#### 2 Using `yml` configuration

Create `ormconfig.yml` in your project root, put an empty object to `default.driver` option. See below.

```yaml
default:
  type: mysql #=TYPEORM_CONNECTION
  driver: {} #THIS'LL FORCE TO mysql2
  host: localhost #=TYPEORM_HOST
  port: 3306 #=TYPEORM_PORT
  username: xxxx #=TYPEORM_USERNAME
  password: xxxxx #=TYPEORM_PASSWORD
  database: xxx #=TYPEORM_DATABASE
  entities: #=TYPEORM_ENTITIES
    - dist/**/*.entity.js
  migrations: #=TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS
    - migration/*.js
  cli:
    migrationsDir: migration #=TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR
```

When use `yml`, make sure there is no other `ormconfig.*` in your path.

Comment: Not sure if this was released later. But thanks indeed! I will accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In `MysqlConnectionOptions` have the driver object and defaults to `require("mysql")`, you can set it to `require("mysql2")`. Hope can help u.